# Why is DATETIMEVALUE Rolling back one day?

Tags: formula

I have a DateTime Field that seems to me to be behaving incorrectly. I am 8 (PST) hours off GMT.

If I put in the formula field:

> DATETIMEVALUE("2018-01-04 01:00:00")

I will get:

> 1/3/2018 5:00PM

I don't understand the 14 hour offset and why the date rolls back.

TIA

Comment: If you are going to down vote me at least tell show me the stupidity of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is actually an 8 hour offset (not 14), and you're right if you're looking to your time zone as the cause.

When you do

```
DATETIMEVALUE("2018-01-04 01:00:00")
```

Salesforce is representing that date-time value in GMT, which is the time zone where all date-time values are stored. Note that 01:00:00 is 1 AM, not 1 PM - that's the difference for you between 8 and 14 hours.

When the value is displayed, the GMT value that is stored is converted to your time zone, in this case by subtracting 8 hours. Doing so returns a date and time on the previous day, the final value `1/3/2018 5:00PM` that's shown to you.

The examples in [Using Date, Date/Time, and Time Values in Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_using_date_datetime.htm) under "Converting Between Date/Time and Text" and "A Note About Date/Time and Time Zones" may be helpful.

I try to steer clear of converting DateTime values to and from text whenever possible, both because it is so easy to make this type of mistake and because Salesforce has limited support for parsing text date formats.